# call method from activemailer view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

Is there a way to call a method from the actionMailer html file the same way a view can call to a method in a controller?

ActionMailer:

```
class ModelEmailerMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  helper :application
  layout 'model_email'

  def user_mailer(user)
    ...
    mail(to: user.formatted_email, subject: "email subject")
  end

  def function_call(user_info)
    ....
    return modified_user_info
  end

helper_method :function_call
```

ActionMailer View file 'model_email':

```
...
user.each do |a|
  modified_user_info = function_call(a)
end
...
```

right now I don't even get an error message. I get an empty email with the correct subject, but no body.

EDIT 1: If I can't place the function in the actionmailer, can I create and link a separate controller to the view?

Comment: Your mailer is only for sending emails, nothing else.

Comment: @blelump, question updated.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your question. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: if you don't get an error, it probably works. can you paste the real code instead of your pseudo code? there is probably a bug in it